# eclipse and tomcat- couldn't load tomcat server configuration at

Tags: eclipse, spring, jakarta-ee, tomcat, web

I try run spring MVC application via tomcat. I attached to preferences_> server tomcat. But when i start `Run On Server` next i press finish button. And i see `couldn't load tomcat server configuration at /Servers/Tomcat v6.0 server at localhost-config. The configuration may by corrupt or incomplete.` Project have to good because it is sample project generated via Spring Tools from template. How fix it?

Comment: Does your server start if you just try to run it via the `Servers` view and/or without any application deployed to it?

Comment: I started tomcat for `./tomcat6 start`.